# why static analyzer is not showing a leak?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, clang-static-analyzer

Here is a piece of code which i have in my source file. the memory management says to add a release and nil if you have a retain in the property. I am not doing it and when i run the static analyzer also, shes not complaining why ? should i enable special settings to show this as a error or leak ?

what could be wrong ? is that a developer's responsibility or it is just a best practice which is not enforced by the compiler or analyzer ?

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *label;
@sythesize label;
-(void) dealloc
{
    //[label release];
    //self.label = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Are you doing anything with the label? I bet if you run with IBOutlet UILabel you'll get the leak.

Comment: i dont know . . will the release and nil help ?

Comment: I think I'm saying that if you do something with the label, you'll get a leak, then if you release it properly (which I think youu're doing above) it will remove the leak.